# How to plot a cartesian plane in R?

Tags: r

I'm doing an exercise which says:

> "Calculate the percentiles 0, 5, 10, ..., 95 and 100 for the variable "Integrated monthly salary" and graph
> in a Cartesian plane its values on the axis of the abscissa and of the accumulated relative frequency on the ordinate axis"

I do

````
 > bd_tarea[8]
# A tibble: 80 x 1
   `Sueldo mensual integrado (Pesos)`
                                <dbl>
 1                              7958.
 2                              4536.
 3                              8182.
 4                             19754.
 5                             18500.
 6                             21185.
 7                              8295.
 8                             27416.
 9                              7913.
10                              7995.
# ... with 70 more rows
    smi<-as.numeric(unlist(bd_tarea[8]))
    x1<-quantile(smi,prob=seq(0, 1, by=0.05))
    > x1
       0%        5%       10%       15%       20%       25%       30% 
    3126.910  4383.412  4924.368  5558.289  5994.584  7139.342  7628.446 
      35%       40%       45%       50%       55%       60%       65% 
    7827.277  7939.390  7984.861  8208.760  8322.271  8877.204 12311.410 
      70%       75%       80%       85%       90%       95%      100% 
    14962.240 18789.390 20453.054 21824.469 23463.207 25330.793 30332.340 
    > y1<-prop.table(bd_tarea[8])
    > plot(x1,y1)
    Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
    'x' and 'y' lengths differ

How can I fix it?
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
    'x' and 'y' lengths differ

```> dput(bd_tarea[8])
structure(list(`Sueldo mensual integrado (Pesos)` = c(7958.36, 
4535.86, 8181.61, 19753.86, 18500.43, 21185.16, 8294.74, 27415.66, 
7913.14, 7994.64, 8355.92, 5859.71, 6005.7, 8266.08, 7956.89, 
5230.78, 23788.44, 7778.79, 12952.44, 7845.29, 5950.12, 16171.32, 
7141.73, 3711.99, 7166.74, 3413.68, 3126.91, 5482.29, 25303.08, 
22172.28, 7448.42, 19656.27, 8385.4, 11966.24, 8168.51, 7842.18, 
23970.7, 20501.11, 5610.09, 4731.75, 21763.09, 8186.21, 7963.13, 
12990.17, 3452.14, 8231.31, 26699.61, 7132.18, 5130.62, 20441.04, 
22547.93, 4418.75, 15994.35, 24567.59, 7799.6, 4571.86, 22270.71, 
25857.34, 9193.31, 9642.4, 9000.48, 15770.32, 13956.41, 20274.14, 
7716.38, 5571.7, 30332.34, 7849.25, 4945.77, 14615.92, 7705.6, 
6990.19, 7972.91, 8517.6, 7322.3, 8272.43, 21588.71, 8795.02, 
23427.07, 6391.15)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
````

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Please edit the question to indicate what it is doing now that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Hello Olga, welcome to SO. We can help you if we understand your data (you could share bd_tarea[8] using dput). I guess that since you use prop table your data will differ in length against your quantile vector. That's why it's mentioned that your lengths differ. Please, I suggest you to click on the asking questions link provided, that helps us to help you.

Comment: @Alexis Oh sorry, i put now what bd_tarea[8] is :D

Comment: Hi Olga, please, could you type in the R console: `dput(bd_tarea[8])` and copy the result and paste it on your question? There are 80 observations, in that way I can help you.

Comment: @Alexis I just edited now and i add it

Answer (score 0):

to solve your question I used your data:

```
bd_tarea <- structure(list(`Sueldo mensual integrado (Pesos)` = c(7958.36, 
4535.86, 8181.61, 19753.86, 18500.43, 21185.16, 8294.74, 27415.66, 
7913.14, 7994.64, 8355.92, 5859.71, 6005.7, 8266.08, 7956.89, 
5230.78, 23788.44, 7778.79, 12952.44, 7845.29, 5950.12, 16171.32, 
7141.73, 3711.99, 7166.74, 3413.68, 3126.91, 5482.29, 25303.08, 
22172.28, 7448.42, 19656.27, 8385.4, 11966.24, 8168.51, 7842.18, 
23970.7, 20501.11, 5610.09, 4731.75, 21763.09, 8186.21, 7963.13, 
12990.17, 3452.14, 8231.31, 26699.61, 7132.18, 5130.62, 20441.04, 
22547.93, 4418.75, 15994.35, 24567.59, 7799.6, 4571.86, 22270.71, 
25857.34, 9193.31, 9642.4, 9000.48, 15770.32, 13956.41, 20274.14, 
7716.38, 5571.7, 30332.34, 7849.25, 4945.77, 14615.92, 7705.6, 
6990.19, 7972.91, 8517.6, 7322.3, 8272.43, 21588.71, 8795.02, 
23427.07, 6391.15)), row.names = c(NA, -80L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And then I created two vectors, one with the quantiles as per your question and one with the cumulative quantiles, where I extracted the names, substituted the percentage character and converted to numeric percentage:

```
x1 <- quantile(bd_tarea$`Sueldo mensual integrado (Pesos)`, prob=seq(0, 1, by=0.05))
x2 <- as.numeric(gsub("%","",names(prop.table(x1))))/100
plot(x1, x2)
```

Now the plot is this:

[image]

But you can invert the plot if you want the x axis to be the percentages (just with `plot(x2,x1)`)